# Why won't the "total" value update when run multiple times?

Tags: python, python-2.7, return-value

The "total" changes the first time I run the function but doesn't return the new value of total so when I run it again it's the same value as before I ran it the first time?

```
total = card[1].value

def hit(total):
    #print (str(hit.counter))
    print("You draw the " + string(card[hit.counter]))
    total = total + card[hit.counter].value
    print(str(total))
    hit.counter += 1
    return hit.counter
    return total
```

the function is called here:

```
choice = raw_input("\n1. Hit\n2. Stay\n")
    if (choice == "1"):
        hit(total)
```

This is the same problem simplified

```
x = 1
def call(x):
    x = x + 1
    print x
    return x
call(x)
```

every time this is run it outputs 2 and doesn't update the new value of "x = x + 1"

Comment: You have two returns in your function. Your code never executes `return total`. Try using `return hit.counter, total` and use two variables on the receiving end where you call the function `hit`, one to store `hit.counter` and other to store `total`

Comment: This did not solve my problem, made no difference what so ever

Comment: Then provide more details in the code like how you are calling the function, how you are storing the returned values. Without that, it's hard to guess things. Provide a working code which reproduces your problem

Comment: You're never modifying the value of the total variable outside of the function

Comment: It looks like your function `hit` shares the same name as some other kind of object (`hit.counter`). Make sure to have unique names for different objects.

Comment: @Moberg I think he uses the `hit` function as a storage for `counter` actually. This is technically correct in Python (functions are objects and can have attributes), but very bad practice and quite brittle when used this way.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers it's a temporary name whilst trying to fix my current problem

Comment: The current problem is almost completely to do with reusing names. Each variable should get its own name. Don't reuse the same name for multiple things.

Comment: @J.walker in your code, `hit` is the `hit` function, not "a temporary name". You can't expect to write working code if you don't understand what you're doing.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice could you please avoid inept suggestions ? Thank you.

Comment: You should change your code to avoid using a global variable `total`. Learn how to pass parameters and return values between your functions.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Please avoid making personal insults. They violate the SO code of conduct. If you wish to discuss the content of my comments, please address it directly.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice where have you seen a "personal insult" ? I didn't say you were inept, I said your suggestion was inept. This is neither personal nor an insult. As to why it's inept: just removing the `total` param from the function signature will not work (it will raise an `UnboundLocalError`), so then you'd have explicitely declare `total` as a global in `hit`, and we all know that globals are evil, and you obviously don't need a global here.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thank you for the feedback. Even though you used the word "inept" as an adjective for the noun "suggestion" the phrase was totally unnecessary to make your actual point.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I know you can add properties to functions like that, but seeing that the code accesses `hit.counter` before it is initialized to anything, I figured that it was not used like that. (You would get an AttributeError)

Comment: @Moberg indeed, I assumed it was set in another (unposted) part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have a global variable called `total`. You also have a local variable called `total`.

When you are in the function, the local `total` will *shadow* the outer global one so updates to `total` inside the function will only update the local variable.

Comment: unless you store the returned value also in a variable called `total` as `counter, total = hit(total)`

Comment: Yeah but that is an assignment outside the function.

Comment: But then after assignment if you pass it again to the function, the assigned value to the global variable is passed to the local variable

Comment: @Bazingaa sure.

Answer (score 1):

> This is the same problem simplified

```
x = 1
def call(x):
    x = x + 1
    print x
    return x
call(x)
```

And ? What do you expect ? That the global `x` will be automagically updated after the last line ? Sorry but that's not how it works. Within `call()`, `x` is a local name, totally unrelated to the outer global `x`. When you call `call(x)`. If you want the global `x` to be updated, you have to explicitely rebind it:

```
def call(x):
    x = x + 1
    print x
    return x

x = 1
x = call(x)
```

I strongly suggest you read this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

EDIT:

> "I want it so when I run the hit() function a second time, the total is the total of the last time I used it"

It's your responsability (the responsability of the code calliing this function I mean) to store the total somewhere and pass it back on the next call:

```
# Q&D py2 / py3 compat:
try: 
    # py2
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    # py3
    pass 

def call(x):
    x = x + 1
    print(x)
    return x


x = 1
while True:
    print("before call, x = {}".format(x))
    x = call(x)
    print("after call, x = {}".format(x))
    if input("play again ? (y/n)").strip().lower() != "y":
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
total = card[1].value

def hit(total):
    print("You draw the " + string(card[hit.counter]))
    total += card[hit.counter].value
    hit.counter += 1
    return hit.counter, total

hit_counter, total = hit(total)
```

as bazingaa has suggested, you are not reaching the return for the total.  if you want multiple values returned, you can do that as above and the use them as shown above in an assignment.

Comment: This didn't solve his/her problem. Check the OP's reply to my comment

Comment: I've tried this and also just removing hit.counter so total is the only thing being returned and it still doesn't work

Comment: right, i suggest you post the entire piece of code you're using including the card array and the way you consume hit function

Comment: @J.walker "does not work" is a totally useless description of a problem (cf http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). This answer does _exactly_ what _you_ asked for: it returns the new total too. If you expect something else, you have to make your question clearer.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers It doesn't return the new total, so by saying "it still doesn't work" I mean his "solution" did not fix my problem and it still doesn't work. I done exactly what was suggested and I had the same problem. I didn't realise I had to spell it out.

Comment: @J.walker it DOES return the new total. But you don't seem to understand what "returning" mean.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Why don't you educate me. If you understand it so well then why haven't you got a solution to my problem? When I change my code the way suggested, the total still doesn't update then next time I run it

Comment: @J.walker have you seen my answer ? You'll notice that the solution is already in Landar's one : you have to rebind total (the global var) to the return value of `hit()`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I have tried this and had the same issue, nothing changed.

Comment: @J.walker you keep on repeating that "nothing changed", but obviously in the above code snippet if you add a "print(total) before the call to `hit` and another after the call to `hit` the value of total will have changed. As I already mentionned (and Bazinga did too), repeating that "it does not work" is not going to help. It might not do what you expect but you didn't explained what you expect nor even post a proper MCVE and no one here has mind-reading abilities AFAICT.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I want it so when I run the hit() function a second time, the total is the total of the last time I used it. This does not happen though, the total stays at the same value. This is my issue that I have and nothing I try seems to fix it. The simplified version I sent that you changed also has the same problem.

Comment: "I want it so when I run the hit() function a second time, the total is the total of the last time I used it" => it's your responsability (the responsability of the code calliing this function I mean) to store the total somewhere and pass it back on the next call.